# Template for pull request reviews

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

GitHub allows for creating [PR templates](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository). Is it possible to do the same, but for pull request **reviews**?

An example of such would be adding a review checklist, like the following:

```markdown
- [] Have all the GitHub checks passed?
- [] Is there any redundant code?
- [] Could any optimization be applied?
```

Comment: Note that the first is better done by setting your repo not to allow merges unless all checks have passed; you don't need a reminder if it's not possible. The second one is better done with an automated check; don't make humans do what a computer can. The third is subjective, but you could make the job easier by using a PR action that compares benchmarks of the base and PR branches; not as a check but a comment on the PR. And there are [code analyzers which can find simple, likely performance problems](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-performance/cops_performance.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GitHub, there are no templates for pull request reviews. A GitHub action allows you to do something when a draft PR is changed to the `ready_for_review` state:

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - ready_for_review
```

For example, you can post a comment that contains checkboxes in this step, e.g. by usíng **marocchino/sticky-pull-request-comment**. I have created a comment in [this PR](https://github.com/cadamini/cadamini.github.io/pull/8#issuecomment-1349695716) and I am excited about how well this works.

**Full GitHub action example:**

```
name: "Pull request checklist"
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - ready_for_review
jobs:
  pull_request_info:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[set-output name=branch;]$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF})"
        id: extract_branch

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Show checklist
        uses: marocchino/sticky-pull-request-comment@v2
        with:
          header: show_checklist
          message: |
            - [ ] Checklist item 1
            - [ ] Checklist item 2
```

For more options, check out the:

- [Sticky pull request comment repo](https://github.com/marocchino/sticky-pull-request-comment)
- [GitHub actions workflow events documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target)